# send_keys() method doesn't work for entering Passcode on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver

When I try using `send_keys()` method for the below screen to try to enter digits 
[image]

but I get the below error

```
.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys}
```

I tried workarounds such as invoking keyboard by cmd+k or `drive.get_keyboard()` but nothing works

Please suggest which method should be used here to enter the passcode for automated testing or any other approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to click or tap, the individual elements(numbers) instead of using sendKeys, usually you use sendKeys for textfields,textareas or similars.

Comment: Clicking/tapping on individual number keys worked.